# Passing bmp file/Image as parameter in wcf service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am trying to pass a BMP file as a parameter in a WCF Service. I'mm getting an error when the size of the BMP file is 350kb. When I pass a small file of 10-20 kb it runs perfectly.

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large. 

[OperationContract]
byte[] ConvertData(Bitmap bmp);
```

I have tried to solve the issue with changing IIS setting following this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jiruss/archive/2007/04/13/http-413-request-entity-too-large-can-t-upload-large-files-using-iis6.aspx but no luck

My Server web.config is

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240000"/>    
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="ReDrawImgService.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="ReDrawImgService.IService1"/>
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

My Client Web.Config is

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240000"/>

</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="ReDrawImgService.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="ReDrawImgService.IService1"/>
        </service>
    </services>

    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8012/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceClient.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your readerQuotas, try to set maxStringContentLength to 2147483647 as well, and make sure this config is set on **both ends**.

So both the server and the client need to have these values. It's no help if the client is allowed to send a large file, if the server will reject it anyway.

What is the value of `maxArrayLength` on the wcf server application

Comment: HI Thanks for your reply i have changed maxStringContentLength to 2147483647 in both my configs but still getting the same error<br/>and maxArrayLength  is the same on both server and client

Comment: When you are debugging this, do you get any more details than what is given in your post. Usually when this fails, the exception will point to what is wrong, for example that content is longer than maxStringContentLength for example.

Comment: I have passed a bmp file as parameter, the size of the bmp file is 350 kb

when i pass a small file of 10-20 kb it runs perfectly,but giving error on 350 kb file

Comment: I have a service that sends files as well ( up to 2-3 MB) and I set the following values on both ends: maxArrayLength, maxStringContentLength, maxReceivedMessageSize. I also set MaxDepth to 128, but that is unrelated to the image sending i believe. You set some values I don't however. Maybe you should try to remove them? Those aremaxRequestLength of the httpRuntime, maxBytesPerRead, maxNameTableCharCount, maxBufferPoolSize. Remember on both ends ;)

Comment: HI , i have removed them from both my server and client configs yet giving the same error:( is there something to do with the iis, can you send me the sample project of your image service, I have updated web.config in Question as well

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a sample project, and my live project is restricted, so I have to strip it down to a minimum if I will be able to send it to you. Can you please post **both** web.configs (complete content) in your question, and I'll see if I see something strange on one of the ends :)

Comment: hi , no problems, i have uploaded both of my configs in the question ,please have a look thanks

Comment: It seems that you have configured your bindingconfiguration correctly, but that you are not using it. In both you client and service configuration you have set `bindingConfiguration=""`. That means you are using the default values regardless of what you have put inside the `<bindings>` part of the configuration. You have to choose which binding configuration to use for the endpoints, so set `bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"` on the **service** endpoints. Let me know how it turned out.

Comment: Thank you so much that solved my issue can you give me your email address so i can be in contact with you further:)

Comment: Great to see that it resolved your issue. Those problems are a bitch to find, since you cannot actually debug anything, so you have to search search search.

Comment: I'll rather not put up my e-mail here. but if you have further questions, just mention my name in a comment, and I'll get a notice in here. Then you have the advantage that someone else miht know the answer to your problem as well :)

Comment: NO Problem i have already marked your answer as correct Thanks @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen

Comment: Hi fez. There is a difference between upvote, and accepted answer. Check the little checkmark you can click underneat the votes for each answer. I would recommend doing so for all the answers to your other questions as well. That makes it much easier for others that land on this page to see if the answer was a match to the question or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25137/discussion-between-fez-and-oyvind-knobloch-brathen)